# Enforcing type hierarchy in TypeScript even when types are "same enough"

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

TypeScript uses "structural subtyping" to determine if two types are compatible, which allows me to do a *surprising* thing like:

```
abstract class Food {
}
class Vegetable extends Food {
}
class Fruit extends Food {
    // doFruitThings() {}
}

class FruitBowl {
    addFruit(fruit: Fruit) {}
}

new FruitBowl().addFruit(new Vegetable()); // Whaaaaaat?!
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=5&pln=9&pc=29#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYge2wEwQG8AoAX2JTQwDUBTAc1olGVoVoA8JaA7PDHPiJkKqdFigBXAJaJO3PgNwESCNQgD0GhHmyYpsgCoALaT3pgAFAEoi5cpXH6ZEAELYA7smHqEwPHjOspYAZgYQAFwSLraE9sQ8tB7Rsu5eNgB0-oHhlonJdIzMIKw21gDcQA)

Note that the above snippet doesn't emit a compiler error until you **uncomment** the `doFruitThings()` method and the types become *structurally* incompatible.

But - I would **prefer** that the compiler detects that my `Vegetable` is not a `Fruit`, even though they currently share the same properties/functions. I'm in the early stages of designing my API and am using types to flesh it out before providing implementation, and am constantly being tripped up by types that "suddenly" become incompatible even though, in my mind, they were not compatible to begin with.

**Question:** Is there any way to configure `tsc` to emit a compiler error in the above playground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use different techniques, even if there isn't an "official" way. For example, with class branding:

```
abstract class Food { }

class Vegetable extends Food {
    _vegetableBrand!: string;
}
class Fruit extends Food {
    _fruitBrand!: string;
    // doFruitThings() {}
}
class FruitBowl {
    addFruit(fruit: Fruit) {}
}

// error!
new FruitBowl().addFruit(new Vegetable());
```

This method is even used by TS team. It doesn't throw at runtime, but allows you to exclude structural compatibility. `brand` suffix is from TS team guidelines.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=43#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYge2wEwQG8EBfAKDJTQwDUBTAczolGToToA8I6A7PDDnxEyCMQgD6AN0bNWdAEIx+AQgBcCSFACWvBgG4y5KuixQArtsRce-QbgKFR4iQDMLVpcFUatug85iAPRBCHjYmB4QACoAFv5gABQAlETkxqimkZYQCtgA7sgi4gjAeHjZVonuORqVEKmE6RQhHFBQ2FAqZLx0+WY5eYUpAHRlFVGJvf30TCwgbCnJ+kA)

There are other ways, you can [read more here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping), however in this case interface branding seems the best hypothesis.